# imported existing maven project and build sucess but i see import stat are showing error in java files

Tags: eclipse, maven, compiler-errors

once maven install executed all jars downloaded in .m2 folder and showing build success. Even though i see all jars in .m2 folder , eclipse is still showing error in some java files for import statement. if manually add those jars in javabuild path error are getting resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Often times you need to do the following:
`Right click on project, Maven, Update Project` or just use `Alt+F5`.